# Any clues on this Unity code not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this function here to duplicate a UIPanel(Prefab) and its components. It duplicates, then succesfully assigns a objectname and enable/disable the Interactable setting of the button component. But the part where it sets the ''OnClick'' on my button does not work. I dont understand as I can play with other options of this button component...

Yes the function Click exists.
Yes I included my using using System.Collections.Generic; using UnityEngine.UI;

Any Help? Thanks.

```
public Text Title;
public Button Btn;

public void CreateEventSquares(string keyval, string valueval)
{
    string Event = (keyval);
    string Link = (valueval);
    Debug.Log("Event :" + Event + "Link is :" + Link);
    NewPanel = Instantiate(Event0);
    NewPanel.transform.SetParent(EventPanel.transform);
    NewPanel.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    NewPanel.name = keyval;

    //Sets the button action to trigger Click function (Not Working)
    Btn = NewPanel.GetComponent<Button>();
    Btn.onClick.AddListener(Click);
    Btn.interactable = false;

    //Sets the title same as keyval (This Works)
    Title = NewPanel.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    Title.text = keyval;

}
```

Click

```
public void Click()
{
//do This
}
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean here? Be aware that runtime added callbacks via code will not be visible in the Inspector .. they will still be called when you click that button ...

Comment: That it did not show up in inspector, which I expected as everything I did up to now always updated there and showed, exept adding the callback to the button. I did not know it would not.

Answer (score 0):

I've re-created this in Unity with your code and it's working perfectly fine for me! **I think it's highly likely you are being thrown by the fact that the function is not showing up in the on click portion of the button in the Unity Inspector.**
Try putting a debug.log in your click function and see what happens.
If you wanted to still define functions in the inspector you would have to use a Unity Event and then subscribe it to the onclick.

```cs
    [Serializable]
    public class ButtonClickedEvent : UnityEvent { }

    [SerializeField]
    public ButtonClickedEvent m_OnClick = new ButtonClickedEvent();

    Btn.onClick.AddListener(Click);

    void Click ()
    {
       m_OnClick.Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: You are right, it triggers the function even tho its not showing in the inspector.... Weird,.. Can you give me a quick example of this with Unity Event? Thanks !

Comment: @SOMEONE Sure thing! Using the following code you can define the functions that will be called in the Inspector just like you would with a  button, however it was my mistake that you can't actually update the buttons 'true' onlcick with this, however, you could add an event listener and have a function that would call m_OnClick.invoke(); to run the functions defined in the inspector as part of the m_OnClick object. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does ! I appreciate your input ! ;)